# Can't make race condition, is my code running sequentially?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, race-condition

I'm trying to demo a race condition in Python with following code but always get expected value `0`. Is there something wrong with my code just it's just not "intensive" enough to trigger the race condition? Thank you.

```
import threading
import time


def race_cond():
    foo = 0
    flag = threading.Event()

    def mutator():
        flag.wait()
        nonlocal foo
        foo += 1
        foo -= 1
        foo += 1

    ts = [threading.Thread(target=mutator)
         for i in range(10000)]
    [t.start() for t in ts]
    flag.set()
    [t.join() for t in ts]
    return foo

for i in range(100):
    print(f'Expecting 10000, actual: {race_cond()}')
```

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock also means you probably won't see a race condition with this code.

Comment: Looking at `dis.dis(mutator)` the modifications to `foo` are definitely not atomic, so in theory it should be possible to have a race condition.

Comment: I GIL is a bytecode level one-a-time execution limitation. The code above could still be executed intervened to cause race condition. @TomDalton

Comment: Yep fair point.

Answer (score 0):

`mutator()` doesn't mutate anything; in fact, it throws an error, because you're trying to change a local variable you haven't defined in that function. In order to change `foo` you need `global foo` in the function.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I just corrected my code but still not got unexpected value printed.